# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

Tags: java

My android + Ksoap [axis 2]  application's tomcat console shows this error continuously

It's not mention any class which I created. Then I'm unable to get idea about it. There are many classes in my web service project.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
        at org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.deserialize(BeanUtil.java
:630)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.processRequest(RPCUtil.java:15
3)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.jav
a:206)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic
(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusines
sLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMe
ssageReceiver.java:114)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostReq
uest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:1
46)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java
:861)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.proce
ss(Http11Protocol.java:606)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:48
9)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Nobody can answer you until you describe your problem clearly with some code. But What have you tried to solve this issue. This is simple error message that can be resolved If you see it once.

Comment: Which part of `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` is confusing to you?

Comment: its not mention any class which i created.then i'm unable to get idea about it.there are many classes in my web service project

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html

```
Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array.
```

Comment: thanks dear android_dev_.its not mention any class which i created.then i'm unable to get idea about it.there are many classes in my web service project

Comment: From your question it seemed like you didn't know what the error stood for.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I've solved that kind of problem avoiding complex types (like Lists and using Arrays instead) as the method's parameters.

I think this is a best practice when deploying web service methods.

So a signature of a web service method *sync*

```
public String sync(List<Operation> ops, String station, String sync_date)
```

need to be modified as this

```
public String sync(Operation[] ops, String station, String sync_date)
```